# Google's Empty Cache and Hard Reload behavior

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching

I'm developing a website and I'm doing this using JS Cookie:

```
var defaultPageSize = Cookies.get("default-page-size");
if (defaultPageSize === undefined) {
    defaultPageSize = 50;
    Cookies.set("default-page-size", 50);
}

$(document).on("change", ".page-size-select", function () {
    Cookies.set("default-page-size", $(this).val());
});
```

And when I clear the cache through the settings, it reverts to the default page size of 50. But opening Developer Tools, right clicking the refresh button and hitting Empty Cache and Hard Reload, does not revert to the default page size.

Can anyone explain why?

I'm not super concerned about the discrepancy but it does make me curious as to how Google's Empty Cache through settings works differently from the option in Developer Tools or whether this is just a quirk of the package I'm using or the settings our sysadmin imposes on us.

Comment: Are you sure you've got the cookies checkbox checked when clearing it from the console?

Comment: Where would I find this option?